# FireDAC - How to execute Stored procedure with default parameters?

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, firedac, default-parameters

i have created following stored procedure on MS SQL Server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sppl_ParamTest
 @ID int = 666
AS
 BEGIN
  SELECT @ID;
 END
```

And trying to call it with FireDAC (without creating any parameters):

```
FCommand:TFDCommand;
...
FCommand.Params.Clear;
FCommand.SQL.Text:='sppl_ParamTest';
FCommand.CommandKind:=skStoredProc
if FCommand.Params.Count=0 then
FCommand.Open;
```

But stored procedure returns NULL(supose to return 666)

As i understood, its caused by FireDAC magic power to query each procedure meta data, before procedure actually calls.

Is it possible to solve this ?

Comment: You can specify the parameters yourself if you turn of meta flag in fetchoptions, this is described in the [manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Executing_Stored_Procedures_(FireDAC))

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting this options to

```
FetchOptions.Items:=[]
```

or

```
FetchOptions.Items := FetchOptions.Items - [fiMeta]
```

Will prevent FireDac from querying meta data, and will allow to use param defaults.

Thanks to whosrdaddy

Comment: Please could you explain:  which component, FDCommand or FDStoreProc you are using that solves your problem, how you are getting it to "use param defaults" and how you are accessing the results of the invocation to obtain the value 666?

Comment: You can use any FDCommand or FDStoredProc.

FDStoredProc.ProceudreName:='sppl_ParamTest';
FDStoredProc.FetchOptions.Items:=[];
FDStoredProc.Open;
ShowMessage(FDStoredProc.Fields[0].AsString); //666

Answer (score 4):

I added your definition of `sppl_ParamTest` to my Sql Server 2014 and executed the following code after minimal configuration of an FDConnection to point it at the server & database on it.  The FDQuery is fresh from the component palette, with only its Connection property set.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'sppl_ParamTest';
  FDQuery1.Open;
  Caption := FDQuery1.Fields[0].AsString;
end;
```

The form's caption displays `666` as expected.

Partial DFM (user name and password omitted):

```
  object FDConnection1: TFDConnection
    Params.Strings = (
      'Database=MATest'
      'Server=MAT410\ss2014'
      'DriverID=MSSQL')
    LoginPrompt = False
    Left = 32
    Top = 16
  end
  object FDQuery1: TFDQuery
    Connection = FDConnection1
    Left = 104
    Top = 16
  end
```

**Update** I think that the OP's problem is most likely arising because of a flaw in the implementation of TFDCommand and TFDStoredProc.  Executing

> sppl_ParamTest default

in Sql Server Management Studio correctly returns

> 666

So does opening an FDQuery with `sppl_ParamTest default` (or just `sppl_ParamTest`) as its command text.

However, with a TFDCommand's CommandText set to the same value, calling `Execute` on it produces this error

> Could not find Stored Procedure 'MATest.dbo.sspl_ParamTest default'

Equally, doing

```
FDStoredProc1.ParamByName('@ID').Value := 'default';
```

(unsurprisingly) provokes the error

> Could not convert variant of type (String) into type (Integer)

on calling `FDStoredProc.Open` and has so far resisted my attempts to set a parameter type which will accept 'default' and correctly execute the sp.

Also, attempts to invoke the FDCommand with `EmptyParam` as the input parameter value fail to return the 666 value.

Comment: You are using query to execute stored procedure. Not FDCommand. FDCommand is used to populate In-Mem dataset.

Comment: Your question was "Is it possible to solve this ?"  My answer is "Yes, use an FDQuery and the problem doesn't arise in the first place."

Comment: I cannot use queries to populate in memory datasets. Your solution is simillar to change text to 'exec sspl_paramtest'

Comment: Well, you didn't mention in-memory datasets, but anyway you can definitely populate them from FDQuerys.  Iirc, you simply assign the Data property of one to the other.

Comment: Why not ?, what's the problem populating an FDMemDataset with the result of an FDQuery ?, you can, for exemple, use the FDMemDataset1.CopyDataset to copy that data.

Comment: Because changing component to Query to call StoredProcedure is not right way to pass default parameter. Query makes possible to use SQL Injections, and basicly, not disigned to be used that way you suggest

Comment: Valery, a Query can be executed without danger of SQL injections, you just have to define its parameters as you do on an stored procedure (instead of concatening the values directly on the SQL.Text). Or in this case with no parameters at all, so it would never have malicious code injected. And yes, stored procedures are designed to also be called on SQL statements, as the samples on MS Documentation show https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The comment about Sql inject seems nonsense to me.  It is no more prone to Sql injection than a parameterised query.

Comment: Yes, i can use Query. It it means i should never use TFDStoredProcedure or TFDCommand to call StoredProcs, since they can not call them right way. Dont think its a good solution.

Comment: " Dont think its a good solution"  Surely, the correct conclusion is that TFDCommand's implementation is flawed?

Comment: Your solution is to use different component. And stop using TFDStoredProcedure/TFDCommand,  for what they were exactly designed.  Since they cant call Stored Procedures correctly. 
What is completly wrong way of solving this.

I can also use TADOStoredProc in this case.

Comment: 1. FireDac calling undocumented stored procedure - sp_columns_100 (with "sppl_ParamTest" as parameter,use profiler)
2. Populates his own Params collection with "NULL" values. 
3. Call real Stored Procedure. 

Now im looking the way to prevent 1,2

Comment: @Valeriy.B, see my comment under your question.